# Figma: How can I create a rectangle with border rounding going to the inside

Tags: figma

I want to create a shape as shown in the image below. I only want the black. The grey should be cut out. I thought I could cut out the grey quatre circle from a black rectangle, but I don't know how. So I basically want a triangle where one side is rounded going inwards. The cut out must be transparent (the grey in the picture). How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In the middle of the upper toolbar you can use the boolean operators to substract on element from another.

[image]